# Profile subtitle not shown on Meta

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, meta

Subtitle under the name of the profile is not shown on Meta Stack Overflow. If this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) why is it hidden?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Repros on Windows 7 64-bit, Waterfox 56.2.3

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't see a subtitle on your profile page, either here or meta.

Comment: This is probably related to Jobs or something... It doesn't show up on any other SE sites either.

Comment: @astonearachnid I was looking at the OPs profile, not mine.

Comment: @DavidPostill Can you see the subtitle on my Meta profile?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Ah. Now I understand . No I can't see it.

Comment: Images edited with freehand circles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z95zN.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/gea3E.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title shown there is drawn from the value set on your profile itself (the Title field on the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab) *or* from your developer story (the title listed for your current position).

There's no developer story on meta, so that last one's out, but the Title field *is* synchronized between meta and main - so it *could* be shown. However, showing it is predicated on Jobs integration being enabled, and that's currently only enabled on Stack Overflow itself - no other site or meta site is eligible.